# Does anyone knows how to fix Intel+Nvidia gamma problem?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, intel, gamma

This is problem on HP laptop which has 2 video controllers.

By using prime-select you can choose Intel or Nvidia.
If you choose  "prime-select intel", then xgamma working, but you are using low speed video controller.
If you choose  "prime-select nvidia" then xgamma not working, but you are using high speed.
On the same laptop in Windows even if you use Nvidia, you still can open Intel panel and change gamma settings separately.

Does anyone knows a way to fix configure gamma when prime profile is Nvidia?

Comment: Have you checked the option in Nvidia X Server Settings? And I doubt that in Windows when running with Nvidia the settings in Intel panel had much of an effect while still running with the same Nvida card (they would after changing to Intel).

Comment: Nvidia has not such option, no in Windows, not in Linux.  
On my laptop  2D always rendered in Intel, Nvidia renders only 3D

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj5rg.png Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: No, there is no such option in nvidia settings. No in Windows either

Comment: I'm showing you a picture of the Nvidia X Server Settings. Is yours different?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IeZbcwD.png

Answer (score 0):

I fond it!!!

this command will give you display name

> xrandr

and then  this command change it gamma!!

> xrandr --output  **Display**   --gamma 1:1:1